# Add colour overlay onto of video background

Tags: html, css

I would like this background video to be darker but trying to add a background colour hasn't worked. I also tried creating a pseudo element `.video-container video:before` with a z-index but nothing changed.

My other peep is that the card is only responsive on the x-axis, and just gets cut off when the screen shrinks from below. I attached a picture to demonstrate what I mean. It's my first time with bootstrap it's thrown me off my learning.

Many many thanks.

edit: I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.video-container video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 0;
 
}

.video-container video:before {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: black;
}
```

[[image: screen not adjusting to height changes]

```css
html,
body,
header,
.view {
    height: 100%;
}

.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.video-container video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 
}

.video-container :before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
}

.card {
    background-color: rgba(0, 162, 255, 0.199);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <div class="view video-container">
      <video src="video/background.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="mx-auto col-xl-5 mb-4 mt-5 pt-5">
          <div class="card">
            <form>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <h3 class="text-white">
                    <strong>Login</strong>
                  </h3>
                  <hr />
                </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <i class="fas fa-user text-white"></i>
                    <label class="text-white" for="name">Username</label>

                    <input
                    type="text"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    class="form-control"
                    required
                    >
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock text-white"></i>
                    <label class="text-white" for="pass">Password</label>

                    <input
                    type="password"
                    id="pass"
                    name="pass"
                    class="form-control"
                    required
                    >
                  </div>

                  <div class="text-center mt-5">
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="myButton">
                      Login
                    </button>
                    
                    <a
                    href="#"
                    class="pt-5 text-white d-block"
                    style="font-size: 14px"
                    >
                    Forgot Password
                  </a>
                  <a
                  href="signup.html"
                  class="pt-5 text-white d-block"
                  style="font-size: 14px"
                  >
                  Don't have an account? Sign Up
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using a pseudo element on top of the video-container will work, but it needs a content: ''; declaration. Also width and height need to be set and you will need to think about z-indexes for the video element itself so the black (I assume with opacity<1?) doesn't cover the input boxes. You also have  a space before the :before which should not be there.

Comment: I thought I had content declaration for the pseudo element, which I've added into my original post :/ I also did set the width and height